# Can ExpressJS - be told to load partial view from redis or mongodb?

Tags: express

I would like to have the templates to be stored in say redis or mongodb.

Is there a way to tell express to load partials/templates from a database ?

**Edit**

Looking at the code on https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/view.js I guess you'd have to write your own View...correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell express to load partials/templates from a database ?

As in, does express have a feature to just do this with an extra configuration option or something along those lines. No. Definitely not.

As in, is it possible, yes, it is. You'll have to write the code to lookup your templates, render them to HTML, and send them in the response though.